# Is std::async a valid helper to destroy heap allocated object

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, asynchronous

Consider a large set of heap allocated objects used to transmit computation result from other threads. Destroying these can be an expensive task.

I am in a scenario where these object are not needed any-more and I just want them to be *garbage collected* without blocking the main thread. I considered using `std::async` the following way to destroy them asynchronously:

```
#include <memory>
#include <future>
#include <vector>

struct Foo
{
  // Complex structure containing heap allocated data.
};

void f() {
  std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Foo>> graveyard;

  // Process some foo and add them in graveyard.

  std::async([fooMoved = std::move(graveyard)]{});
}
```

In the specific program I am working on, using Visual Studio, profiling seems to confirm that this is *faster* – with respect to the main thread at least – than just letting graveyard destroy its content at the end of `f` scope.

Is this kind of improvement a glitch specific to the conditions of my test or is it a reliable way to deallocate large set of heap data? Do you see any potential drawbacks? Is there a better way to perform a similar task?

Comment: I strongly suggest thinking about **pooling** rather than asynchronous GC. it will also help claiming the resources faster and both construction and destruction will preform faster and more smoothly. if you do want to use asyncrhonous destruction at least use a thread pool and not `std::async` as the last may open a new thread for each new task

Comment: Performing any time-consuming task in a separate thread has the  potential speed things up. That's not specific to deleting large numbers of objects. If there is a better way in your case depends entirely on what you are doing.

Comment: The way your are using `std::async` is implementation dependent i.e it may be blocking or asynchronous..thus not a deterministic portable solution. The other thing is, I am not sure if any implementation as of now provides thread pool facility to execute tasks by `async`, if it does not and if your `f` function gets called in the critical code path, then I do not think its a good idea to launch a thread each time.

Comment: Note that the main heap must be shared, so there is contention.  The above could be slower than the single-threaded case if the main thread is allocation-bound.

Comment: I believe the temporary `future` created by `async` and destroyed right away will block in its destructor until the task is complete. So the code as written doesn't actually do anything asynchronously.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik That's exactly what I was thinking. But the profiling data I get seems to go against this reasoning. I do observe a performance increase. Hence this question.

Comment: My strong suspicion would be some defect of measuring methodology. Somehow, your measurements may not be including the time it takes to run the `future`'s destructor.